# Getting reports from oracle data base

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I am working on a php script that generates a report from an oracle database. I want to improve the quality of the results I am getting. I want the table to have the totals at the bottom. 
This is what I am getting. I want the deciles to be in order either assending or descending cos I have faled to do it with sql(there is a decile 10 that i cant control).
I also want to have the totals of the two columns (total_decile_count and FULL_KYC) down there.

```
ECILE   TOTAL_DECILE_COUNT  FULL_KYC    PERCENTAGE
Decile 9    5091             1936           38.03
Decile 8    12472           5580            44.74
Decile 7    29927           14838           49.58
Decile 6    36481           18770           51.45
Decile 5    33460           18356           54.86
Decile 4    30454           17010           55.85
Decile 3    24243           14175           58.47
Decile 2    16912           8245            48.75
Decile 10   4231            2122            50.15
Decile 1    8801            4835            54.94
Bal.barred  1188354        115601           9.73
```

This is my code. Dont mind the sql because there is no problem there. My interest is the php code.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1500M');
$c = oci_pconnect("xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
if (!$c) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $e['message'],E_USER_ERROR);
}
$s = oci_parse($c, "WITH 
  dcl AS (
 select count(n.msisdn) FULL_KYC,case when n.decile_group is NULL then 'Bal.barred' else n.decile_group end decile_group  
from (select distinct (a.msisdn)msisdn,b.segment,b.decile_group 
from table1 a full join table2 b on a.msisdn=b.msisdn)n,
(select distinct msisdn from (
            select case
              when substr(msisdn,1,1) = '7' then ''||msisdn
              when substr(msisdn,1,1) = '0' then ''||substr(msisdn,2,9)
            else msisdn end msisdn from table3))p
where n.msisdn=p.msisdn
group by n.decile_group),

base as (select decile,total_decile_count from table4 )

select base.decile, base.total_decile_count,dcl.full_kyc,round(((dcl.full_kyc/base.total_decile_count)*100),2) Percentage
from dcl left join base on base.decile=dcl.decile_group order by base.decile desc");


if (!$s) {
$e = oci_error($c);
trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $e['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
$e = oci_error($s);
trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $e['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
$ncols = oci_num_fields($s);
echo "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {
$colname = oci_field_name($s, $i);
echo " <th><b>".htmlentities($colname, ENT_QUOTES)."</b></th>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach ($row as $item) {
echo " <td>".($item!==null?htmlentities($item,
ENT_QUOTES):"&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main problem is proper ordering you can achieve this easy in sql, like below (only `order by` part is important, rest is for presentation):

```
with test_data as (
  select 'Decile 1' decile, 7 total_decile_count, 4 full_kyc, 38.00 Percentage from dual
  union select 'Decile 2', 12, 5, 45.00 from dual
  union select 'Decile 3', 11, 19, 42.00 from dual
  union select 'Decile 11', 11, 8, 8.87 from dual 
  )
select * 
  from (
    select decile, total_decile_count, full_kyc, percentage from test_data
    union
    select 'Sums' decile, sum(total_decile_count) total_decile_count, 
      sum(full_kyc) full_kyc, sum(percentage) percentage from test_data)
  order by case when decile like 'Decile%' then 1 else 2 end,
    length(trim(decile)) desc, decile desc
```

Output:

```
DECILE       TOTAL_DECILE_COUNT    FULL_KYC    PERCENTAGE
Decile 11                    11           8          8,87
Decile 3                     11          19         42,00
Decile 2                     12           5         45,00
Decile 1                      7           4         38,00
Sums                         41          36        133,87
```

Comment: Thanks a great deal for this. I solved the order issue. Now my only problem is how to email this results as an excel file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad I could help. As for emailing results in spreadsheet I think you should create another question, because this is completely new topic and others users will be certainly more helpful.